# Removing run / fork := true from sbt results in [runtime, notfound] exception, and if not removed i can't take user input from console

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sbt, akka-stream

```
import Dependencies._
import sbt.Keys.{libraryDependencies, resolvers}
import sbt.Resolver

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.1.0"
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"
ThisBuild / scalacOptions ++= Seq("-language:implicitConversions", "-deprecation", "-feature")

val AkkaVersion = "2.6.17"
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
 .settings(
   name := "sensor-nws",
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.scalameta" %% "munit" % "0.7.26" % Test,
     excludes(("com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % AkkaVersion).cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)),
     excludes(("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.2.0").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)),
     excludes(("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.2.0").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13))),
   resolvers ++= Seq(Resolver.typesafeIvyRepo("releases"),
     "Artima Maven Repository" at "https://repo.artima.com/releases",
     "spark.jars.repositories" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
   )
 )

//netty-all replaces all these excludes
def excludes(m: ModuleID): ModuleID =
 m.exclude("io.netty", "netty-common").
   exclude("io.netty", "netty-handler").
   exclude("io.netty", "netty-transport").
   exclude("io.netty", "netty-buffer").
   exclude("io.netty", "netty-codec").
   exclude("io.netty", "netty-resolver").
   exclude("io.netty", "netty-transport-native-epoll").
   exclude("io.netty", "netty-transport-native-unix-common").
   exclude("javax.xml.bind", "jaxb-api").
   exclude("jakarta.xml.bind", "jaxb-api").
   exclude("javax.activation", "activation").
   exclude("jakarta.annotation", "jakarta.annotation-api").
   exclude("javax.annotation", "javax.annotation-api")

run / fork := true
Test / fork := true
```

*if run / fork := true is removed from sbt then: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/ajitkumar/Downloads/flice/sensor-nws/target/bg-jobs/sbt_4be36759/target/135c9252/81ecd14d/hadoop-client-api-3.3.1.jar (No such file or directory)

if not removed the below code results in

```
    println("Enter the directory path")
    val dir = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
    print("dir ->", dir)
``
[info] Enter the directory path
[error] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: I have reported this as a bug on sbt gitHub page.
https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/7055

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem gets solved after adding `run / connectInput := true` to build.sbt.
more on this: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/229